# error: invalid operands of types 'time_t(time_t*)' {aka 'long long int(long long int*)'} and 'int' to binary 'operator*'

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

## Problem

I'm trying to compile my `main.cpp` file to `main.exe` using the command:

`g++ main.cpp -o main.exe`

but I'm encountering an error.

Here's part of my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

long double temperature;
long double weight;
long double length;
long double time;
string unit_select;
string convert;

void newline()
{
    cout << "\n" << endl;
}

void input_unit_convert()
{
    cout << "Enter Unit" << ":" << " ";
    cin >> convert;

    std::transform(convert.begin(), convert.end(), convert.begin(), ::toupper);
}

void input_temperature()
{
    cout << "Enter temperature" << ":" << " ";
    cin >> temperature;
}

void input_weight()
{
    cout << "Enter weight" << ":" << " ";
    cin >> weight;
}

void input_length()
{
    cout << "Enter length" << ":" << " ";
    cin >> length;
}

void input_time()
{
    cout << "Enter time" << ":" << " ";
    cin >> time;
}

// some code here

    do {
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "(T)" << " " << "Temperature" << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "(W)" << " " << "Weight" << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "(L)" << " " << "Length" << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "(TI)" << " " << "Time" << "\n" << endl;
        
        cout << "Select unit" << ":" << " ";
        cin >> unit_select;

        std::transform(unit_select.begin(), unit_select.end(), unit_select.begin(), ::toupper);

        if (unit_select == "T" || unit_select == "W" || unit_select == "L")
        {

// some code here

            }
            else if (unit_select == "TI")
            {
                for (auto& time_list : time_units)
                {
                    cout << "\n" << time_list << "\n" << endl;
                }

                input_unit_convert();

// some code here

                }
                else if (convert == "MIL")
                {
                    input_time();

                    newline();

                    cout << "Second" << ":" << " " << time * 31536000000 << endl;
                    cout << "Milisecond" << ":" << " " << time * 31536000000000 << endl;
                    cout << "Microsecond" << ":" << " " << time * 31536000000000000 << endl;
                    cout << "Nanosecond" << ":" << " " << time * 31536000000000000000 << endl;
                    cout << "Picosecond" << ":" << " " << time * 31536000000000000000000 << endl;
                    cout << "Minute" << ":" << " " << time * 525600000 << endl;
                    cout << "Hour" << ":" << " " << time * 8760000 << endl;
                    cout << "Day" << ":" << " " << time * 365000 << endl;
                    cout << "Week" << ":" << " " << time * 52142.8571 << endl;
                    cout << "Month" << ":" << " " << time * 12000 << endl;
                    cout << "Year" << ":" << " " << time * 1000 << endl;
                    cout << "Decade" << ":" << " " << time * 100 << endl;
                    cout << "Century" << ":" << " " << time * 10 << endl;
                }
```

And I get this error:

```
main.cpp:1265:61: error: invalid operands of types 'time_t(time_t*)' {aka 'long long int(long long int*)'} and 'int' to binary 'operator*'
 1265 |                     cout << "Century" << ":" << " " << time * 10 << endl;
      |                                                        ~~~~ ^ ~~
      |                                                        |      |
      |                                                        |      int
      |                                                        time_t(time_t*) {aka long long int(long long int*)}
```

## Expectations

#### What did I tried

I changed the string from `double` to `long double` and still got the same error.

#### Expectation

I expect a `main.exe` file in the same directory as the `main.cpp` file.

Comment: The compiler is confusing your variable `time` with the function `time`. I'd change the name of the variable.

Comment: Side note: When the question wizard asks what you expected, it intends for you to describe the behaviour expected contrasted with the behaviour observed. It's pretty much meaningless for a question that doesn't compile because you obviously expected the program to compile.

Comment: When I set the compiler to be more anally retentive, a lot of extra interesting warnings pop up: https://godbolt.org/z/P9vrWs4jG

Comment: Here's that again with `time` changed to `gtime` fo avoid the collision with the `time` function: https://godbolt.org/z/h3K51oreb The last one you don't have to worry about, it's a side-effect of the incomplete code example, but the other two you may need to address.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]? Emphasis on **minimal** and **reproducible**. Most of the code shown is completely irrelevant to the problem in question.

Comment: _Side note:_ Professional programmers rarely use `using namespace std;`. Do yourself a favor: stop using it yourself. Instead, just type out `std::cout`, `std::cin`, `std::string`, and so on, every time you use a name in the Standard Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a couple of other users have pointed out, `time` is a function name and you can't multiply by functions. That's what `types 'time_t(time_t*)' {aka 'long long int(long long int*)'} and 'int' to binary 'operator*'` means. Renaming the variable to `g_time`, `gtime` or `dTime` will fix the compilation error.

The use of "magic numbers" (around line 50) is also unnecessary and will lead to compiler warnings. Declare some constants to explain the purpose of this multiplication, like:

```
static const double Years_in_Millennium = 1000.0;
static const double Months_in_Millennium = Years_in_Millennium * 12.0;
static const double Days_in_Millennium = Years_in_Millennium * 365.0;
static const double Hours_in_Millennium = Days_in_Millennium * 24.0;
static const double Seconds_in_Millennium = Hours_in_Millennium * 3600.0;
static const double Microseconds_in_Millennium = Seconds_in_Millennium * 1000000.0;
```

and use them between lines 49 and 60.